# Export bitmaps from Fireworks

Tags: adobe-fireworks

Suppose I have multiple, say, around 50 bitmaps in my Fireworks (CS6) file. There are pages from a scanned file. 
I want to export each of them to a separate file.

There is a function in Fireworks that permits to export all "Layers" to files, but not "Bitmaps"...

Is there a way to save each bitmap as a file, without having to do 50 operations individually?[image]

Comment: Fireworks has some scripting capabilities, but from the looks of it you will be (a lot) faster doing 50 operations manually than researching and implementing an automated process.

Comment: I manually created 50 new layers (folders), and manually moved a bitmap by folder, then the export allowed me to export all layers(folders) to a separate image automatically...

Answer (score 1):

I know it's way too late to answer Serge, but I wanted to do the same, and the only way was to move each bitmap to a new layer. Fortunately there's a less painful way (still painful).
On Layer window drag the bitmap to the New Layer icon and it'll create a copy of the bitmap into a new layer. Then you can delete your bitmap and it becomes easier to know which you did already, and those you didn't do yet.

Cheers.